# Big O notation with special inner loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I would like to have some help regarding analyzing the followings Big O notation.

**Case A:**
The inner loop only runs once in the worst scenario

```
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

       if (i==nums.length-1 && nums[i] == 3){
          for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
           print();
          }
       }
    }
```

The worst case scenario is an array that finish in 3. Is this O(N) or O(N*N)?

The way I analyse this is the following:

- The outer array runs N times= 1(n)
- The inner loop in the worst case runs just 1 time = 1

So , n*1 = O(n) , am I ok with the analysis?

Does it makes sense "n*1" or should be "n+1"?

**Case B:**

The inner loop runs always except if `i` is the first element

```
   for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
     if (i!=0){
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
          print();
        }
     }
   }
```

The way I analyse this is the following  :

- The outer array runs N times= n
- The inner loop runs N -1 times =n-1

So , n*(n-1) = O(n*n) , am I ok with the analysis?

I am very confused with those cases, thanks !

Comment: You are right on both accounts. First is `O(n)` and second is `O(n^2)`. In the first case, even if the inner loop ran, say 3 times each iteration, it would still be `O(n)`. Constant multipliers are removed in Big O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Case A:

> The outer array runs N times= 1(n)
> The inner loop in the worst case runs just 1 time = 1

I think your reasoning here is probably okay, but as it's written this can't be right. `The outer array runs N times` implies that you count `1` for every iteration of the loop, but `The inner loop in the worst case runs just 1 time` can't be right (under the same definition), as it will have `n` iterations as well (in worst-case, ie. if the last element is `3`). I think on the first line you used `runs = number of iterations` and on the second line you used `runs = starts/finishes`; there's no problem with either, but make sure to be clear and consistent.

You've correctly said that `The worst case scenario is an array that finish in 3`, and in this case it runs the outer loop `n` times (skipping over the inner loop) then on the final iteration it doesn't skip the inner loop, which runs `n` times. This is `O(n+n)` = `O(n)`.

---

Another way to think of it is that the code could be rewritten as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
}

if ((nums.length > 0) && (nums[nums.length-1] == 3)){
    for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
        print();
    }
}
```

Which we rewrite for worst-case scenario like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
}

for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
        print();
}
```

Then the serial nature of it becomes obvious: `n + n` work. The important thing here is that we haven't changed the algorithm in any important way (we haven't effected the worst-case complexity).

### Case B:

Your logic and math here looks good.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and so clear explanation.
You are right i was not very clear and consistent in the first example.
If you have time,could you explain me how you came up with "runs = starts/finishes"?I try to replace the values and still cant understand. Thanks again!

Comment: @AlXx, I was just speculating, but I assumed that when you said `The inner loop in the worst case runs just 1 time` that you meant `runs` to mean that the loop went through ***all*** of its iterations ***once*** (which is the same as saying that the number of times that the loop _started_ or _finished_ going through its iterations is 1).

Comment: Thanks Elliot,i hope more people like you in Stackoverflow.I will mark the question as accepted of course!

Comment: I thougth you were diviing start/finish hahah.Thanks!